# How much does an IOS Library project adds in size to app

Tags: ios, frameworks, size, project, lib

I have a framework I finished writing (with bit code enabled). I want to know how much is my framework is adding to an app after they upload the app to the store.
I understood that i need to archive the app to ad hoc and choose a variant (a device) then recompile with out my framework and see what is the difference.
When i compile the demo app with bitcode. After selecting ad hoc it won't le me select variant xcode returns 14 domain error.When i remove bit code i can see the variants. Is this ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a `Simple View Application` and `archive` then `export` it once with your framework and once without. Then compare the two `IPA` sizes.

#### Update

To have the size for all architectures, export your iPA with the `Export one app for all compatible devices` option.
[image]

If you need to have the size for a special architecture use the `Export for specific devices` option.
[image]

Comment: would this tell me the size for each architecture or fro all of them together ?

Comment: @NoamSegev It depends on how you export your iPA. I've updated the answer with additional details.

Comment: check this answer for more details about bitcode http://stackoverflow.com/a/35175679/7610805